# Changing an attribute from Other Component to filter Data in Angular 13

Tags: angular, web

I have 2 components,component LaptopList having a laptopsList list to store data from an api and LeftbarComponent to filter data (modifying the laptopsList in LaptopListComponent)

I want from the leftbar component to call the getData2 and modify the laptopsList attribute to filter the laptops.
How i can do it?Thank you!

LaptopList.ts:

```
export class LaptoplistComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(public service:LaptopsService){

  }
laptopsList:Laptops[]=[]


  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  this.service.getData().pipe(map(data=>data)).subscribe((res:any)=>{
   // console.log(res.length);
   for(let i=0;i<res.length;i++){
     this.laptopsList.push(new     Laptops(res[i].id,res[i].brand,res[i].price,res[i].screen,res[i].ram,res[i].gpu,res[i].storage,res[i  ].processor,res[i].photo))
   }
   for(let i=0;i<res.length;i++){
     console.log(this.laptopsList[i]);
   }
 });`

LaptopsService.ts:
 `
 export class LaptopsService {

   constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
   }
   getData(){
console.log(this.http.get("http://localhost/projet_api/view.php").subscribe(res=>  {console.log(res);}));
     return this.http.get("http://localhost/projet_api/view.php");

   }
 //filter data
   getData2(data:string="?price=50"){
console.log(this.http.get("http://localhost/projet_api/view.php").subscribe(res=>    {console.log(res);}));
     return this.http.get("http://localhost/projet_api/viewFilter.php");
   }

 }
```

`

what does the leftbar.ts components should have?